# "Say for definite" vs. "say exactly"

Tags: difference, collocations

Is there any difference betwee the colloction *say for definite* and *say exactly*? For example:

> I can't **say** **exactly** how much money I have in my bank account.
>
> I can't **say** **for definite** how much money I have in my bank account.

Comment: To me, they are the same. I would say that '...say exactly...' sounds more natural to a native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both mean the same. Though I can’t say I’ve heard “...say definitely...” ever used. I would say “...say exactly...” sounds better. I would also say that in the US we would mostly commonly use “...say for sure...” or “...say for certain...”